# SSIS DB installaion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssis, ssis-2014

I am kind of new to SQL server database. I am using sql server 2014
Can anyone help me to install SSIS DB. Is it mandatory to install to SSISDB

Comment: If you are looking for the installation instructions then MSDN doc have a detailed documentation done at the below location.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/install-integration-services

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation in BOL shows the process to create the SSISDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/service/ssis-catalog#create-the-ssis-catalog) (SSIS catalog). You will have to have SSIS already installed on the given SQL Server instance before trying to create it.

The only reason this catalog would be required is if you are using the project-deployment model for your SSIS environment. If you are using the file system or SQL Server store/msdb then you do not have to create it.